# What wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation are emitted by the LH2/LOX reaction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, rocket-science, wavelength, combustion

Rocket engines such as the Rocketdyne Rocket System 68 and the Space Shuttle Main Engine use liquid hydrogen and liquid oxygen as propellants. The exhaust from this type of engine is notable in comparison to non-LH2/LOX engines because the visible light emitted is far less intense. The exhaust plume sometimes appears completely transparent.

From a brief study of [chemiluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiluminescence), I understand that the radiation produced during a chemical reaction depends on the electron energy states of the atoms in the reaction. Does the position of Hydrogen (1st period) and Oxygen (2nd period) in the periodic table have anything to do with the wavelengths emitted?

Do other factors besides chemiluminescence contribute to the wavelengths emitted?

Comment: I would guesstimate that the reason why there is a visible flame in hydrocarbon based fuel plumes is because of the carbon particulates from the fuel-rich operation of the engine (to prevent oxidation of the chamber and nozzle). In comparison, as far as I know neither H, H2, O, O2, OH or H2O have spectral lines in the visible that can be excited by the chemical combustion temperature. We can, at most, see infrared emissions of the molecules.

Comment: Actually, a hydrogen flame detector looks in the UV...